# Using EXISTS with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1093

I have this simple query that works on all other database systems, but fails with MySQL:

```
UPDATE points p 
SET p.userid = 5224 
WHERE p.userid = 2532 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM points q
    WHERE q.userid = 5224
    AND q.game = p.game
)
```

I get the following error message:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'p' for update in FROM clause
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't alias the main table in an UPDATE clause. This should work:

```
UPDATE points 
SET userid = 5224 
WHERE userid = 2532 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM points q
    WHERE q.userid = 5224
    AND q.game = points.game
)
```

Comment: and what about the AND q.game = p.game?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
UPDATE POINTS
   SET userid = 5224 
 WHERE userid = 2532 
   AND game NOT IN (SELECT q.game
                      FROM POINTS q
                     WHERE q.userid = 5224)
```

Comment: FYI: `NOT IN` is faster than `NOT EXISTS` in MySQL: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Thanks. +1 from me, but I like Mark's answer better because NOT IN is slower on some other database systems and there the difference is huge (index vs no index), so it is more portable.

Comment: @Milan: `NOT EXISTS` & `NOT IN` are equivalent in SQL Server: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: Oracle: `NOT EXISTS`, `NOT IN` and `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` are equivalent: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/

Comment: I hardly call SQL Server portable, but ok :) Oracle is not the only DBMS there is. There's Firebird, Postgred, SQLite, DB2, Informix, etc.