# How to read a table that I am also updating in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

### Update Statement

```
UPDATE a_fees af set af.audit_id =  get_audit_id ( pubco_id, auditor_id, 
                                                   (SELECT 
                                                    CONCAT ('''', 
                                                      a_fees.fiscal_year, '', 
                                                      fiscal_period_end_month,'',
                                                      fiscal_period_end_day, '''')
                                                   FROM a_fees, a_fiscal_period_end
  WHERE a_fees.fiscal_period_end_id = a_fiscal_period_end.fiscal_period_end_id)
);
```

### Error Message

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'af' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: @grijeshchauhan I think I need to use a loop but not exactly sure how

Comment: Sorry but your query is very much wrong...please describe what you wants.

Comment: First of all, use `FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id` instead of writing `FROM a, b WHERE a.id=b.id`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805009/using-exists-with-mysql?rq=1) , this should work:

```
UPDATE a_fees set audit_id =  get_audit_id ( pubco_id, auditor_id, 
                                                   (SELECT 
                                                    CONCAT ('''', 
                                                      af.fiscal_year, '', 
                                                      fiscal_period_end_month,'',
                                                      fiscal_period_end_day, '''')
                                                   FROM a_fees af, a_fiscal_period_end
  WHERE af.fiscal_period_end_id = a_fiscal_period_end.fiscal_period_end_id)
);
```